# How to make sure that google doesn't index you Azure subdomain?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, search-engine

I have a website on an Azure app service and we are going to go live soon. 
I've followed what has been suggested so I've created a CName to my Azure sub-domain. How can I make sure that google will not index my site as xxx.azurewebsites.net instead of xxx.com ?

Right now I have IP restrictions available, so google cannot see my website and index it, but when we go live both xxx.com and xxx.azurewebsites.net will be open to public. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add permanent redirects (301) in the app.

So if someone accesses a page e.g. aaa.azurewebsites.net/Something, redirect them to aaa.com/Something with a 301 redirect.

It was the first that came to my mind, but Google has more guidance on canonical URLs here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Best you can do is add a robot.txt file for google and other robots that try to index your site.

[Robots_exclusion_standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

The host directive can have the preferred domainname:

```
Host: example.com
```